# how to sort the linux find command by the path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am writing a small shell script. there i want to get all the paths of files recursively. for that i am using bellow code.

```
for entry in `find . -type f`; do
       echo $entry 
done
```

getting the files recursively is okay. but it does not sort by path.

ex : the folder has 1,2,3,rename.sh (The shell script) files and a folder called test. inside that test folder again there are 1,2, 3 files. when i execute this code the out put is like this

```
./rename.sh
./1.png
./test/1.png
./test/2.jpg
./test/3.jpg
./2.jpg
./3.jpg
```

why is it not sorted by path. How do i sort it by the path so the out put wold be

```
./rename.sh
./1.png
./2.jpg
./3.jpg
./test/1.png
./test/2.jpg
./test/3.jpg
```

Comment: As an aside -- reading the output of `find` with `for` is buggy; it falls under the same general category as [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).

Comment: As for "why is it not sorted?" -- because sorting takes time, and there's no point to spending that time when the user hasn't explicitly requested it (unless the filesystem is indexed in such a way that it returns directory entries in order for free -- but that's a matter of which filesystem you formatted your drive with, which flags it's configured with, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you so much for pointing that out... so is there a way that i can achieve what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want content sorted, *do it yourself*. For a list of files, doing that safely means NUL-delimiting the names (so a file with a newline in its name doesn't get read as the names of two separate files and thus split apart during the sort process), and using `sort -z` (a GNU extension).

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' entry; do
  printf 'Processing: %s\n' "$entry"
done < <(find . -type f -print0 | sort -z)
```

See [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for guidance on using `find` reliably, and [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a discussion of the `while read` construct used here.